# Изменение состояние поля Field на readonly в Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, io

Есть Pet Project - тестовый редактор, в котором поле TextBox, которое через библиотеку System.IO методом ReadAllText - считывает данные. Есть задача - добавление функционала в виде Button в блокировании и разблокировании поля TextBox по нажатию. Есть альтернатива - свойство поля - Locked(False/True), но при изменении свойства на True пропадает скролл, это не подходит.
Кто сталкивался с подобной ситуацией прошу помощи. Спасибо.

Comment: посмотрите свойство `Enabled`

Comment: @Exodium Как и с Locked выключается скролл, это не подходит

Comment: [`TextBox.ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) не выключает прокрутку. Попробуйте.

Comment: Согласен, уже нашел ответ - Свойство ReadOnly + Изменение цвета окна. Спасибо.